# Dual boot Mac with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, refind, macbook-air

I have a macbook air with Mac OSX and Ubuntu installed on it.  I have refind installed on the Mac partition.  I am able to boot into the refind screen but my mac partition is not displayed.  I am only able to select Ubuntu 18.04.1.  I have been looking for a few days to see if anyone else has this same issue but haven't found anything.

Comment: If you hold down the option key during startup, does it show both the Mac and the other boot options?  If so, boot to the Mac again and try installing rEFInd from there.

Comment: I have held down the option key during startup but that doesn't give me the mac option.

Comment: See if you can get into Recovery mode then and check your drive from there.  Hold down Command+R as soon as you power it on and see the Apple Logo.  Your OS might have been overwritten.

Comment: I will try that a little later today.  I apologize for the confusion.  I have refind installed on my mac partition and I set the boot order to start with that partition.  I can also see the partition on my disks menu in Ubuntu.

Comment: If I remember right, rEFInd kind of goes to its own area of the drive for booting, then it is able to select either Mac or whatever OS you have installed.  I don't think the boot part gets installed into the Mac partition.  I would try the recovery mode and check the drive from the Utilities there.

Comment: Sounds good, I will try that out and let you know.  Thanks!